# Firefox doesn't play mp4 file in HTML5 video

Tags: html, firefox, ffmpeg, html5-video

I recorded a video with my mobile which had the format ".mp4". Now if I load that video in HTML5 video tag, I get an error `HTTP "Content-Type" of "video/3gpp" is not supported.` Why does Firefox consider the file as `3gpp` although it is an `mp4` file?
If I log the file properties when it is loaded on to browser, I see the following

`{ name: "test.mp4", lastModified: 1434536249000, lastModifiedDate: Date 2015-06-17T10:17:29.000Z, size: 41151959, type: "video/mp4" }`

This means firefox identifies the type as `mp4` only. But doesn't play it giving the error `HTTP "Content-Type" of "video/3gpp" is not supported.`

Comment: what does `ffmpeg -i file` say about the file?

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the mp4 to a mp4 with another codec. I recommend xMediaRecode. If the converted file is working, it must have something to do with your mobile.